# CSS Layout with full size left navbar and header

Tags: css, navigation, fullscreen, html

I would like to have the following layout

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+Header               +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+Nav+                 +
+   +                 +
+   +                 +
+   +      Content    +
+   +                 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

so basically a two column layout with a header. I've checked many CSS layout generators on the net, but they just produced me a result where the left navbar is as big as the content in it. I can scale it with "height:500px" or whatever, but i want it to be fullsize (from top to bottom of browser window) all the time. Changing the value with "height:100%" does not work.
If you want to try it out yourself: http://guidefordesign.com/css_generator.php and then select full page, two column layout, with header to see what i mean. If you want you can tell me which property i have to adjust in the generated css file to make it work

Answer (score 7):

You can try this. It works on the browsers I tested (Firefox, IE7+8, Opera, Safari, Chrome). Just play around with the percentage units for header and columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>for stackoverflow</title>
  <style>
    body, html {
        padding : 0px;
        margin : 0px;
        height : 100%;
    } 

    #wrapper {
        width:900px;
        height:100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #header {
        height:10%;
        background-color:#930;
        width:900px;
    }

    #nav {
        background-color:#999;
        width:200px;
        height:90%;
        float:left;
    }

    #content {
        height:90%;
        background-color:#363;
        width:700px;
        float:left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Good answer but you don't have take control of the `height` property. Simply setting the `width` and `float: left` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at and get the idea from:

- [Super Simple Two Column Layout](http://css-tricks.com/super-simple-two-column-layout/)

[See the demo here.](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SuperSimpleTwoColumn/)

Answer (score 0):

A little general answer: Look into CSS frameworks, like http://www.blueprintcss.org/ - these let you define grids.

Here's a sample page: http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html

Concerning the *height problem*, try out this (should give you 100% of browser window height for your div all the time):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .Container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #123456;
        color: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution you can try, is to give the content area a background image which is repeated vertically (1px height and width of your page). The left side of that image would have the nav background color, and the rest would be the color of the content background color ...